# Trailing zeros not displaying

Tags: php

I have a question. When I have a user height value of 5.10, 4.10, or 6.10 the value of the height is displayed as 5.1, 4.1, or 6.1. However, the data in question is stored in the database as 5.10, 4.10, or 6.10.

Why am I seeing the the values of the 5.1 instead of 5.10.

The format of the data is stored as a Float in the MySQL Database.

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: no idea; post your code and schema

Comment: `5'10` doesn't really look like a float. Floats need decimals. That's more base 12 fractions (which google claims is called a duodecimal)

Comment: So in reality the field in question should not be setup as an float but more as an char field??

Comment: Well if you think about it, if you are storing these numbers as a float, I have to assume the `5'10` is stored as `5.1` and as insignificant zeroes would not normally be shown I would expect to see `5'1` unless I used some formatting when presenting these numbers

Comment: That is correct, I made mistake in the question.  It is stored as 5.10 and coming back as 5.1

Answer (score 0):

If the height values you're referring to are feet and inches, i.e. a value of 5.10 means five feet ten inches, you should probably not store them as floats.

The thing is, in terms of floats, 5.10 and 5.1 are the same number. If you want to store them as floats, you'd need five feet one inch to be stored as 5.01 in order to be able to differentiate 5'10 and 5'1. All of your single digit inch values would need to be stored that way. (5.02, 5.03, etc.)

You could store them as strings instead, but there are some drawbacks to that. Depending on the string format you used to store them, they might not sort properly. (For example: 5'1, 5'10, 5'11, 5'2 ...) It would be difficult to use any aggregate functions on them, (average, etc.)

I think the type that will work best for the database is actually int. Convert the feet and inches to inches before storing. It's easy enough to reformat those values for output. For example:

```
function formatHeight (int $inches) : string
{
    return sprintf("%d'%d", intdiv($inches, 12), $inches % 12);
}

formatHeight(63);  // returns 5'3
```